# How to import key from CERT_CONTEXT into HCRYPTPROV

Tags: windows, ssl, x509

We have Windows code which is heavily based on Crypt* API and keys stored in HCRYPTPROV (asymmetric, both public and private parts). The keys are normally imported from external source using CryptImportKey().

Note: The safety of the source providing this key is out of topic here. Let's say it is safe enough for our purposes.

Now with development going on we need to adopt keys coming from X.509 certificates. Currently code loads certificate into HCERTSTORE through PFXImportCertStore() or obtains it from online CA and then certificate itself can be accesses as CERT_CONTEXT through CertEnumCertificatesInStore.

But I completely failed to find a way to move keys from certificate into HCRYPTPROV. Any ideas are extremely welcome.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

HCRYPTPROV is just a pointer. You cannot *move* keys there.

Have you tried to use the IntPtr property X509Certificate2.Handle yet?